# Why there are so many same routes in Argon template?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am new at web dev and Laravel. I downloaded Argon template, looked for routes of the project and found this :

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Why is that? Why there so many same routes?

Comment: Please read laravel official document here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Laravel adds these two routes to your web.php file

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
```

PS : Laravel dosen't check if the above 2 routes already included in your web.php file so for example if you call make:auth 5 times you end up with

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
```

doubled 5 times

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel PHP artisan Route List command**

Ideally, the php artisan route:list will display display the domain, method, URI, name, action and middleware for the routes it includes in the generated table.

Now, what if I want to show a route list for a particular url, name or method?

Well, in this case, we can use some Term in Artisan Route List.

The syntax of Article Route list is-

**php artisan route:list**

php artisan route:list --TERM=VALUE
List of Terms
--method Filters the routes by method

--name Filters the routes by name

--path= Filters the routes by path (URI). None

--reverse Reverses the order the routes are displayed in the table

-r Reverses the order the routes are displayed in the table (shortcut to --reverse)

--sort The column to sort by. Accepted values are host, method, uri, name, action or middleware

Comment: How is this in any way related to OPs question? How would that solve OPs problem?